# Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using phonegap

Tags: cordova, cross-browser, phonegap

I'm developing a phonegap mobile application which is running on 3000. This mobile application consuming a web service which is in Tomcat. When I tried to connect , I'm getting below error.
Response-to-Preflight-Request-Doesnt-Pass-Access.

I have added a CORS plugin and it is working.
Can anyone provide the solution without plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277435/no-access-control-allow-origin-error-in-meteor-app

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for cross browser issues which are related to Access Control Allow Origin.
1. If you are using chrome browser, add this extension to your chrome([CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)). This plugin will handle the cross browser url pattern issues.
2. Instead of adding the plugin, you can write some piece of code in your application(which is deployed in Tomacat and publishing the webservice).
Add below code to your web.xml

```
 <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

This both ways will work.